# Google Cloud VM IIS hosted site DNS setup

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, dns-zone, google-cloud-platform

I've been running through the google cloud instructional to setup DNS on a custom website but I can't get it to work. Google cloud doco suggests posting on this forum so I'll outline what I've done and hopefully someone can assist, I haven't needed to expose a website before, hopefully I'm missing something simple.

Instructional I followed: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns

**What I have done:**

- Google Cloud VM IIS website works on localhost (via RDP session)
- Google Cloud website works by IP address from my desktop at home
- Google cloud IP address has been made static
- GoDaddy nameservers have been updated to point to google cloud 

  -ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.

  -ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.

  -ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.

  -ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.
- Google cloud - I have created a zone for my .com
- Google cloud - I have 3 record sets under my zone

  -mydomain.com - NS (this was there by default)

  -mydomain.com - SOA (this was there by default)

  -www.mydomain.com - CNAME

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an A record in the Cloud DNS to point to your VM's IP address. You can have more information in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/dns/getting-started).